# Looking for a slicker way of rebuilding this array

Tags: php

I have a data result being returned from my database with multiple rows. The problem I'm having is that I only need a single row for some items and the multiple rows for others and without doing multiple database queries for every item that is needed, I thought I'd rebuild the data array.

What I am ultimately after is to use each item in the array as a string. If the last two items, product and location have multiple rows then I need them returned as strings.

What would be the best way to handle this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cid] => one line
            [model] => one line
            [mfgr] => one line
            [color] => one line
            [orderid] => one line
            [product] => many lines
            [location] => many lines
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            .. repeats for as many rows as were found
        )
)
```

---

Let me rephrase this question. The array that you see above is the array that is produced from my foreach. Array key [0] holds all of the data from my result. Array key[1] simply repeats the data. I need single rows for columns 1-5. Columns 6 & 7 are where I need multiple rows, hence the repeating array keys.

If I had to rebuild this array that way I need, it would look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [single] => Array
        (
            [cid] => one line
            [model] => one line
            [mfgr] => one line
            [color] => one line
            [orderid] => one line

            [product] => Array
              (
                    [0] => many lines
                    [1] => many lines
              )
            [location] => Array
              (
                    [0] => many lines
                    [1] => many lines
              )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of grouping you want to do is the kind of thing databases do best.

Lookup the MySQL documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: Hmm.. This seems like a viable solution and probably the best way of handling it. If I use group_concat, I won't lose the rows where I only need a single row, will I? I'm thinking that this function returns only a single row for some reason. Of course, I will have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you need, here's how

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if(is_array($value['product'])) {
    $array[$key]['product'] = implode(', ', $value['product']);
  }

  if(is_array($value['location'])) {
    $array[$key]['location'] = implode(', ', $value['location']);
  }
}
```

This will turn "multiple lines" in `product` and `location` into a single string with commas.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I believe this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Michael, how do I limit only one row for each of first 5 columns? Remember, I will be getting back the maximum number of the last two columns and that means that the first 5 rows will be duplicates.

Comment: Michael, sorry. This doesn't work because $value['product'] is not an array. I did revise my question though if this helps you.